# Opposite of commensurately

Tags: word-choice

What is an eloquent (preferably non-prefixed) antonym for the word commensurately? I know inequality is sort of similar, but not what I'm looking for.

Example:
She climbed a mountain, but I [non-commensurately] just walked up a hill.

Comment: Can you please provide details, what do you need this word for? Different situations, and scenarios might well require different terms. Did you look up [any antonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/commensurate)? What do you mean by "eloquent"?  The more details you give, the better the answers. Invest a little effort and you will be repaid.

Comment: She climbed a mountain, but I [non-commensurately] just walked up a hill.

Comment: In the answer please, not in comments. Comments have this bad habit of disappearing, trust me. I joke not.

Comment: I added to the question. By eloquently I mean concise and succinct.

Comment: That's quite a profound reflection. What idea do you want to convey, that her achievement was tenfold to one you succeeded in performing? Or do you want to say that the task was far easier for you than for her?

Comment: I suppose incommensurately  doesn't work? (or something like 'less impressively' could be a nice way of putting it)

Comment: @Silicabello - could you also give an example sentence actually using *commensurately* ("*I ate two helpings of the first course and she, commensurately, ate two helpings of dessert"*?.  It's not a word I meet often!)

Comment: @Mari-LouA The idea I'm trying to convey is that the effort put forth is in-equal.

Comment: Bathetically {[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bathetically)} works. Or not.

Comment: @Tom22 I'm looking for a self contained word, not a prefix

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Bathetically describes negatively one side over the other, the word i want could be used as more or less extent than the other, basically just in-equal effort.

Comment: @Dan 'He saved her life, and she responded commensurately with a gift of great magnitude'

Comment: But your target word surely **must** specify a situation where the standard specified is either greatly exceeded or greatly fallen short of.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the word to presume one over the other in my context. I basically just want to convey that the effort was not equal in magnitude.

Comment: 'asymmetrically' is another option but it essentially is a prefixed word itself meaning something slightly different than commensurate

Comment: @Silicabello - if 'I' in fact matched her achievement climbing the mountain, can you complete the sentence?

Comment: @Dan 'I climbed a mountain and she responded commensurately with a feast fit for kings'

Comment: One common way to complete that sentiment (albeit with two words) is *She climbed a mountain; I, **in contrast**, walked up a hill.* If it must be a single adverb, the form would be **contrastingly**, but I wouldn't call it elegant (let alone eloquent). (The simplest way to complete the sentiment may be to use your original phrase without the thing in brackets: "**but** I **just**" already fully conveys that your accomplishment falls short of hers.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe here, the "opposite" would be **merely** + silence.

> She climbed a mountain, but I merely walked up a hill.

I.e., this sentence already provides the aspirational contrast you are looking for without needing an extra word.

Scanning through all those comments, there may not even be a word specifically meaning "non-commensurately", at least not in this context. Concepts such as "unbalanced" and "disproportionate" come to mind, but even if they would fit well, they would add nothing that **merely** had not already stated.

Comment: While 'merely' does complete the example sentence correctly, it instead implies a lack of other components as the definition is 'only' instead of inequality, so it presumes a negative like fore-mentioned 'bathetically'. Disproportionate is the closest I've found also, but I'm looking for a self contained word, not something thats been prefixed.

Comment: @Silicabello If you need to stress inequality, perhaps substitute **barely** for **merely**. You may not need a new word, just the right words.

Answer (score 0):

In the context provided (where 'she' has achieved some to be proud of) an appropriate 'opposite' of 'prideful achievement' might be  ***disappointingly***, perhaps?

Comment: This provides an assumption of disposition beyond the context, and does not provide a reference to inequality so it is not really what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

***Commensurate*** - Having the same measure; of equal extent, duration, or magnitude; coextensive (OED).

A commensurate response matches one thing with another to the same degree.  You might say that a *commensurate* response is a *fitting* response (i.e. Becoming, appropriate, proper, suitable (OED).

The opposite of a '*fitting*' response would be an ***unfitting*** response (*unfitting* - not fitting or suitable; unbecoming, improper (OED)).

*She climbed a mountain, whereas I **unfittingly** just walked up a hill.*